# Microsoft Flow/Power Automate - Selecting current item from a Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I'm conducting a lucky draw to encourage colleagues to post on Yammer, and I want to do the following:

1. Colleague posts message on Yammer
2. Pull a Lucky Draw Participation code from SharePoint List
3. Send colleague an automated message with this Lucky Draw Participation code.

There are only 100 codes, and for obvious reasons, are single-use and cannot be easily reverse-engineered. So I have crafted them in advance by hand.

My question now is... what are the functions I can use can to set up a Flow, that plucks a code from a Sharepoint list (never re-uses it as well), and that this flow would cease after 100 times (i.e. all codes used up)

Thanks!
(Following is the screenshot where I was stuck at...)

[Currently stuck here in MS Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F1Q6f.png)

Answer (score 0):

One example:

1. First, add a flag to your SharePoint list that indicates the code (row) has been used, e.g., Yes/No field named "Used."
2. Use Get Items action that uses the ODATA filter query "Used ne 1" without quotes. That will only pull codes that have not been marked as used.
3. Set Top Count to 1.  Only the next unused item will be retrieved.
4. Use Update Item action to mark that code as Used.
5. Use the output of the Get Items action however you see fit.

Note: You can also add a condition to send you a message that all codes have been used if the length of the output for the Get Items action is 0.